# How to print an object of a foreignkey instead of the entire class to Django administration

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

In my 'models.py' file, I have 2 LOOKUP tables: the 'Part' class and the 'Vendor' class as shown:

```
# Part Lookup table
class Part(models.Model):
    part_id = models.CharField(max_length=64)                               # Part ID
    description = models.CharField(max_length=64)                           # Part description
    pq = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)                # Pack quantity
    mrrp = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)             # Manufacturers Recommended Retail Price                                         
    # Display something in admin
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.id} {self.part_id} {self.description} {self.pq} {self.mrrp}"   

# Vendor Lookup table
class Vendor(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)                         
    # Display something in admin
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.id} {self.name}"
```

I then have another FACT or ASSOCIATION table, the 'Relationship' class as shown:

```
# Relationship association table (Between Part & Vendor)
class Relationship(models.Model):
    part_id = models.ForeignKey(Part, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="part")  
    vendor_id = models.ForeignKey(Vendor, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="vendor")  
    # Display something in admin
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.id} {self.part_id} {self.vendor_id}"
```

The below is my entire 'admin.py' file:

```
from django.contrib import admin

# Import the classes from models.py
from .models import Part, Vendor, Relationship, Transaction, Offer, Supersession, Category, Group

# Django admin title
admin.site.site_header = "Online Parts System"

# Model Admin class
class PartAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # Data headers (must match objects of the Part class)
    list_display = ('id', 'part_id', 'description', 'pq', 'mrrp')

# Model Admin class
class VendorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # Data headers (must match objects of the Vendor class)
    list_display = ('id', 'name')

# Model Admin class
class RelationshipAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # Data headers (must match objects of the Vendor class)
    list_display = ('id', 'part_id', 'vendor_id')

# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(Part, PartAdmin)
admin.site.register(Vendor, VendorAdmin)
admin.site.register(Relationship, RelationshipAdmin)
```

Everything is working really well so far. Unfortunately, in the Django admin page > Relationships table, under the 'Part ID' column, I am seeing every object of the 'Part' class (since I used the ForeignKey line).

I only wish to see one object such as 'part_id' instead of all the others combined.

What is the simplest way to achieve this?

Please see image below. I basically want to simplify the string underlined in red.

[Django Admin Page So Far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BkeNX.png)

Comment: What do you mean by "I only wish to see one object such as 'part_id' instead of all the others combined." ? Could you elaborate please?

Comment: @MehrdadMoradi  Okay, so I've edited my post with an image. If you look at the underlined in red, it is a string representation of all the Python objects within the Part class. I only want to show say the 'part_id' which is '427-06-1110' for example.

Comment: I still don't know what you mean by you wishing to see only `part_id`, what are you intending to do?

Comment: OK, I think I got what you mean. You have defined the `part_id` field as being a foreign key to the `Part` model which will include the full object and show it in the admin dashboard. You want to only show the `part_id` field of the `Part` object instead of the full object in the `Relationship` table.

Comment: @MehrdadMoradi Exactly! Any ideas please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string used in the admin dashboard under the `part_id` column comes from the `__str__` method of the `Part` model. You can change the implementation of the `__str__` method to include only the `part_id`.

```py
# Part Lookup table
class Part(models.Model):
    part_id = models.CharField(max_length=64)                               # Part ID
    description = models.CharField(max_length=64)                           # Part description
    pq = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)                # Pack quantity
    mrrp = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)             # Manufacturers Recommended Retail Price                                         
    # Display something in admin
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.part_id}"
```